# Adding a Security Policy in BackendConfig does not attach it to the backend-services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

My objective is to have all the `backend-services`, that use the External Global Load Balancer, get the Security Policy I have created.

In order to do that, other than manually creating, I have attached a Security Policy to a BackendConfig[1] and that sometimes has backend services get the security policy, sometimes none of the four get it.

How to remove this indeterministic behavior and have all the backend-services get the Security policy?

[1] The BackendConfig:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: <name of the backendconfig>
spec:
  logging:
    enable: true
    sampleRate: 1
  securityPolicy:
    name: "<name of the policy>-{{ .Values.subdomain }}"
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 5
    timeoutSec: 1
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    port: <some port>
    type: HTTP2
    requestPath: /<some request path>
```

I also checked the codebase, as I am leveraging `gloo`, and it has the config where the Service is attached with the above BackendConfig.

Also, sometimes, of the 4-5 backend services that are created (it has horizontal autoscaling enabled), some get [SecurityPolicy] in their `Features` description, some get the actual policy and the Feature, some get none.